# How do I screen capture ReactJS components using PhantomJS?

Tags: reactjs, pdf, phantomjs, png

I am attempting to render my personal ReactJS website (https://irlmap.com) as a png using PhantomJS's boilerplate screen capture script rasterize.js with a 10sec timeout. When I run the script, I get a blank, grey png. When I target other sites, the script works fine.

How do I screen capture ReactJS components using PhantomJS?

Answer (score 0):

I now this is possible using server-side rendering, but this seems to impose a lot of constraints. Read more [here](https://medium.com/styled-components/the-simple-guide-to-server-side-rendering-react-with-styled-components-d31c6b2b8fbf).